# «Поэтому то, о чём ты говоришь, (—) это отношение двух величин». Нужно тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

**Поэтому то, о чём ты говоришь, (—) это отношение двух величин.**

Ставится ли тире в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Поэтому то, о чём ты говоришь, — это отношение двух величин.**

Здесь ЭТО — связка, а перед связкой тире ставится в обязательном порядке.

**Но повтор "то — это" нежелателен, нужно что-то изменить, например:**

Поэтому то, о чём ты говоришь, является  отношением двух величин.

Поэтому всё, о чём ты говоришь, — это отношение двух величин.